# Liferay Input Edtior throwing error (__ckeditor.java : 827)

Tags: configuration, liferay-6, maven-plugin, weblogic12c, liferay-aui

I am new to liferay portlets. I am facing a strange issue with liferay-ui:input-editor.
My environment,

- Liferay 6.2 CE
- Maven
- Weblogic 12c

I have a working portlet which have a configuration.jsp for configuring some contents. The portlet works fine if I deploy the portlet using the automatic deployment by copying into liferayAuto folder. But when I deploy the preprocessed manually, I am getting the below error whenever I try to open the configuration. The issue is with liferay-ui:input-editor, as it works fine when I remove the tag. Below is the error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at jsp_servlet._html._js._editor.__ckeditor._jspService(__ckeditor.java:827)
        at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:35)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:188)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:119)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:588)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.include(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:481)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.DirectServletPathRegisterDispatcher.include(DirectServletPathRegisterDispatcher.java:55)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.doDispatch(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:78)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.include(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:53)
        at com.liferay.taglib.util.IncludeTag.include(IncludeTag.java:295)
        at com.liferay.taglib.util.IncludeTag.doInclude(IncludeTag.java:192)
```

In __ckeditor.java the line 827 shows this,

`doAsGroupId = (Long)request.getAttribute("liferay-ui:input-editor:groupId");}`

Any help is much appreciated ...

Comment: Just a hint: As the request is usually not null in a JSP, the NPE is coming from the autounboxing of the `Long` (`doAsGroupId` is a `long`). So you have no request attribute `liferay-ui:input-editor:groupId`. I would guess that some init file is different or missing. But you can easily find this out by comparing the WAR directory that is created when you use the auto deploy with the one that you create manually.

Comment: Help me understand the problem first, you are deploying the war using maven command then it works fine but when you manually paste the war in the deploy folder then the error is coming. is that the case?
or whenever you are trying to configure your portlet it is giving error. please confirm.
Also if you can add a blogs portlet and try to configure its "entry added email" tab and check that it gives the error or not as it is also having ck-editor in its configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `<liferay-theme:defineObjects />` in configuration.jsp solved the issue.